# Fdisk formatted usb not mounting

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, nautilus

I recently used fdisk over gparted to format and partition a USB and now the USB is not automounting and is not showing up in Nautilus, though it is found by `lsblk` and anything else that lists disks

Comment: Ah, _grasshopper_!  But did you use `fdisk` __then__ `gparted`, or `gparted` __then__ `fdisk`? `fdisk` cannot format a partition, only create/destroy them.  `gparted` can create/destroy _and_ format partitions.  What did you do?  Your wording is imprecise and confusing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was more or less covered in the comment by lornix, but I thought I'd post an official answer.

The `fdisk` utility only allows you to partition the disk, and will not format the new partition for you.

If, for example, you partitioned the device /dev/sdc to have one partition (/dev/sdc1), you would have to format it with `mkfs`. Since you are formatting a flashdrive, FAT32 would probably be the best option.

To format the device in my example, I would use `mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdc1`

**However**, I would personally recommend just using Gparted, as it will partition and format the drive for you all in one step with a nice UI.